# Is it possible to modify the bottom search bar *interval*?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I think the technical details of this question go beyond math.SE, but anyway I'll give it a try. I notice that, when browsing questions, the page range that a user can select from are, in general, the first, the last and an interval around the page you are on, for example you get to choose from a list like this: $[1]\cdots[23][24][25][26][27]\cdots[321]$.  In this manner is very difficult to browse in the between space of these questions. Could it be a good idea to modify this "choice range" offering also two intermediate numbers, one between page 1 and the page you are on, and another between the page you are on and the last page?

Comment: Maybe this is more suited for [meta on the main site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Related post on meta.SE: [Adding a button to improve navigation through the questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172246/adding-a-button-to-improve-navigation-through-the-questions)

Comment: Some browser, say firefox, allow you to create url shortcut with parameter. If you are using one of those browser, you just need to set up one and type a few characters into the address bar in order to jump to whatever page you want.  See [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/338647) on superuser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would these intermediate number be something in the middle, like below? 
$$[1]\cdots [12] \cdots [23][24][25][26][27]\cdots [174] \cdots [321]$$
Then I think this is more confusing than helpful. Why $174$, the browsing user will ask -- is there anything special about that page of results? And what if I want page $96$  instead?

If in the process of browsing you want to jump to page number N, you can do that by changing `page=25` (or whatever the current page is) in the URL to `page=N` and hitting Enter.

Comment: Yes, the list would look exactly as you have written. The average user might be confused, but here on math.SE it could be understood and appreciated, don't you think? :)

Comment: It seems that ideally there'll be a textbox where you can input the page number into the results. But that sounds like something that you are going to write into a script later today. Gogogo!

Comment: @AsafKaragila There's already a textbox, provided by the browser at the top of the page. The only inconvenience I see is that when you are on the first page, the page number is suppressed in the URL. This might be my next feature request on Meta.SE.